# Trouble populating Mongo Database from Nodejs

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, mongodb

The following json order has shipping, payment, orderProduct as elements. I am trying to access the individual elements using the code below:

```
 {
"shipping": "{\"nickName\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"firstName\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"lastName\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"addressLine1\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"addressLine2\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"city\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"country\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"province\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"postalCode\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"phone\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"email\":\"gsfsdfdf\",\"shippingInstruction\":\"gsfsdfdfgsfsdfdfgsfsdfdfgsfsdfdf\"}",
"payment": "{\"cardType\":\"Visa\",\"cardNumber\":\"11111111111111111111\",\"expMonth\":\"3\",\"expYear\":\"2019\",\"csc\":\"111\"}",
"orderProduct": "[{\"productId\":\"594fce45734d1d24b915a41f\",\"quantity\":1}]",
"deliveryDate": "2017-07-07T04:00:00.000Z"
```

}

I am using the code below to access the various elements of the json data:

```
router.post('/order/add', function (req, res) {
console.log('order = ' + req.body.order);

var newOrder = req.body.order;
console.log('shipping = ' + newOrder.shipping);
console.log('payment = ' + newOrder.payment);
console.log('orderProduct = ' + newOrder.orderProduct);
console.log('deliveryDate = ' + newOrder.deliveryDate);

var order = new Order({
    shipping: newOrder.shipping,
    payment: newOrder.payment,
    orderProduct: newOrder.orderProduct,
    deliveryDate: newOrder.deliveryDate,
});

console.log("created server order = " + order);

return res.json(200, order);
```

})

But the  shipping, payment, orderProduct, deliveryDAte are return undefined.

Comment: Link to plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/7oqKLljE6dxvotcBMKP2

Comment: What does your code print out when data is posted to this endpoint? What are you trying to do? The title refers to problems populating a database, but your code doesn't perform an insert.

Comment: I was having a problem formatting all of  the code on here so I posted it to Plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/7oqKLljE6dxvotcBMKP2?p=info